# Removing {} from column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I was working on Tableau. I read a file with different columns in it. One of the column had value within {}, for instance, {0097837}. I just want value 0097837 and don't want {}. How can I do that?
Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: You could try using the split functionality in the data area: https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2016/05/data-prepping-and-data-cleaning-tableau-explained. I would try to clean your data first though before plugging it into to tableau

Answer (score 2):

Create a calculated field and use the regexp_replace function.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([the field], "[{}]", " ")
```

Comment: Works Wonders.. Thanks!

Comment: @Sarthak_D, If this answer resolved your question, you can mark it as answer, which do not need more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following as a new calculated field, this will be your field with the {} removed:

```
REPLACE((REPLACE(ATTR([YOUR_FIELD]),"{", "")),"}", "")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but I am getting Null as the output!